# Serial stops reading after about 6 hours

Tags: python, serial-port

When reading the serial port in python, all works fine until after hours where receiving data stops. This happens both on a laptop running Linux and on a Raspberry PI 2. Sending data still works at that point.
The source is still sending data (now and again). Restarting the python script helps.
The source sends small packages (4 - 12 bytes) and interval times may vary from minutes to over 12 hours.

My code, just only the receiving part, extracted from a bigger part, looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter
import os
import serial

class Transceiver():
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.port = serial.Serial(
            port = "/dev/ttyUSB0",
            baudrate = 38400,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            timeout = 0
        )
        self.ReceivedData = bytearray()
        self.Time = 0

    def Receiver(self):
        while (self.port.in_waiting > 0):
            # Receiving data
            self.Time = 0                           # Reset time elapsed to 0
            self.ReceivedData += self.port.read(1)  # Add data to bytearray
        if (self.Time == 20):                       # Some time elapsed, packet considered complete
            print(''.join('{:02x} '.format(x) for x in self.ReceivedData))
            self.port.reset_input_buffer()
            self.ReceivedData = bytearray()
        if (self.Time < 2000):                      # Just avoid running to 0 again
            self.Time += 1                          # Increment time elapsed
        root.after(5, self.Receiver)

root = tkinter.Tk()
transceiver = Transceiver(root)
transceiver.Receiver()
root.mainloop()
```

It is just this receiving part that stops working after hours, I am trying to find the root cause.
So the above script is just an extract from a bigger script.
It controls the lights in the house. I want to run it on a raspberry PI, instead of a PC. The R'PI has a little 7" touch screen.
The bigger scripts has some decoding of the received data and updates a very simple GUI, just a bunch of small rectangles with some short name as text in it, indicating which lamps are on and off, and they act as buttons too, to toggle the lamps on and off. All works well, apart from the receiving part, though, in the end it may be possible that some other part disturbs the receiving part.

I have just started running just the above extraction of the script, to see if it keeps working without the GUI updates. I suspect the function Receiver fails to be restarted after some time. I need to have the above script running for a day to see of it keeps receiving though. I will update with the findings.

Update: The above script keeps working. The above is the extraction of a bigger program where only this part stops working after some hours. Receiving stops, but transmitting keeps working, hence I did not include that part.

By now I found the problem. In the receiver function, a decode function is called where above is the print line. Without calling the decode function, there is no problem. The decode function has some conditions, depending on the packet length and some values. Code for one of these conditions contained an error. I always started to run the script again in early evening, and then about 6 hours later a timer (at a fixed time late in the evening) would send the offending packet (a different format) that then caused the problem. The packet was not at fault, but my decoding of that packet.

Strange is that the script kept working, only the reception part stopped. I thought it stopped silently, but I printed quite a lot in this stage, hence I didn't see the error message telling me the problem of the use of an uninitialised variable. It's not in the above code. Hope the above code is useful for other people.

Comment: do you get any error when the serial stops sending? is it possible that it could be a hardware issue (assuming you're using a USB to UART cable or something)?

Comment: Thanks, no I do not get any error, it silently stops working.

Comment: hmm, I was able to run this code successfully for several minutes communicating to an ESP32 from my laptop. Is it possible for you to provide more of the code?